# Vertical lines only in certain columns

Tags: tables, line, vertical

For a table in my thesis I want to show a verti
cal line only spanning 3 out of 5 columns.

My current table is:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\caption[Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen]{\textbf{Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen}}
\label{t:praeppcrcycler}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\midrule
Temperatur & Zeit & \\
\midrule
98 \si{\degreeCelsius} & 3 min &  \\
& & \\

98 \si{\degreeCelsius} & 30 s &    \\
58 \si{\degreeCelsius} & 20-30 s & 30-35x \\
72 \si{\degreeCelsius} & 20-60 s &  \\

& & \\
72 \si{\degreeCelsius} & 3 min & \\
4 \si{\degreeCelsius} & $\infty$ & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which gives me this table
[image]

I do however want to add a vertical line spanning column 3, row 3 to 5 as in this picture
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, from one being from Tatooine to another! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is. I slightly simplified and improved your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, multirow, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedRight}
  \sisetup{range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
  \caption[Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen]{\textbf{Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen}}
  \label{t:praeppcrcycler}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \midrule
    Temperatur & Zeit & \\
    \midrule
    \SI {98}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}\SI{3}{min} & \\
                                     & & \\
    \SI{98}{\celsius} & \SI{30}{s} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} \\
    \SI{58}{\celsius} & \SIrange{20}{30}{s} & \multicolumn{1}|c}{30–35$\times$} \\
    \SI{72}{\celsius} & \SIrange{20}{60}{s} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} \\
                                     & & \\
    \SI{72}{\celsius}& \phantom{0}\SI{3}{min} & \\
    \phantom{0}\SI{4}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}$\infty$ & \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Exactly what I was looking for. I was messing around with \multicolumn but couldn't get it quite right so this is very helpful!  Also thanks for improving my code as far as siunitx is concerned - the spacing is now just as I wanted

Comment: @Mico: How did you guess? I'll fix that. Thanks!

Comment: The non-ASCII-character-gremlin strikes again! (`–`, `∞, and maybe others...)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, Master of the Gremlins! I tamed the ∞ gremlin. But I don't see the point with `–`. The (utf8) endash has no problem with T1 encoding?

Comment: @Bernard - About the utf8-encoded en-dash character: We may never know when and how your code may get copied by somebody into their own documents -- and we won't know if they'll employ the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Best not to find out...

Comment: @Mico: But for accented letters, I never type, say `\`{e}`,  I always type `è`.  What's the difference? For maths, I understand, but for ordinary text?

Comment: I think we're on rock-solid ground, coding-wise, if we stick with ASCII encodings (and, if need be, `--`). It may be the case that `è` is encoded the same in Latin9 and UTF8; however, that may not be the case for other characters, such as the "German" `ß` ("sharp s") character. If we stick with ASCII, we'll minimize the chances of creating unnecessary frustrations with any future users of our code.

Comment: If we all stick to utf8, there's no problem either. I don't understand why people still use latin1, or 9, or applemac, whereas all modern editors know utf8 (and use it by default).

Answer (score 7):

The following may be what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip,textfont=bf,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen}
\label{t:praeppcrcycler}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\midrule
Temperatur & Zeit & \\
\midrule
\SI{98}{\degreeCelsius} & 3\,min &  \\[2ex]
\SI{98}{\degreeCelsius} & 30\,s  &  
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{|l@{}} 
            \\ 30--35$\times$ \\ \\
         \end{tabular}} \\
\SI{58}{\degreeCelsius} & 20--30\,s & \\
\SI{72}{\degreeCelsius} & 20--60\,s & \\[2ex]
\SI{72}{\degreeCelsius} & 3\,min    & \\
\SI{4}{\degreeCelsius}  & $\infty$  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks tatooine fellow! :-) Just as helpful as the solution of Bernard, which I can wrap my head around a very little bit easier though!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the row, columns and cells. So it's possible to use Tikz to draw whatever rule you want after the main array by putting an instruction in the `\CodeAfter` (`\tikz \draw (4-|3) -- (7-|3) ;`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedRight}
  \sisetup{range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
  \caption[Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen]{\textbf{Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen}}
  \label{t:praeppcrcycler}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
    \midrule
    Temperatur & Zeit & \\
    \midrule
    \qty{98}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}\qty{3}{min} \\
                                     & & \\
    \qty{98}{\celsius} & \qty{30}{s} \\
    \qty{58}{\celsius} & \qtyrange{20}{30}{s} & 30–35$\times$ \\
    \qty{72}{\celsius} & \qtyrange{20}{60}{s} \\
                                     & & \\
    \qty{72}{\celsius}& \phantom{0}\qty{3}{min} \\
    \phantom{0}\qty{4}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}$\infty$ \\
    \midrule
  \CodeAfter \tikz \draw (4-|3) -- (7-|3) ;
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible to use the command `\Block` (built-in in `{NiceTabular}`) and its key `borders`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedRight}
  \sisetup{range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
  \caption[Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen]{\textbf{Temperatur-Zyklus-Konditionen für präperative PCR-Reaktionen}}
  \label{t:praeppcrcycler}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
    \midrule
    Temperatur & Zeit & \\
    \midrule
    \qty{98}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}\qty{3}{min} \\
                                     & & \\
    \qty{98}{\celsius} & \Block[borders=right]{3-1}{} \qty{30}{s} \\
    \qty{58}{\celsius} & \qtyrange{20}{30}{s} & 30–35$\times$ \\
    \qty{72}{\celsius} & \qtyrange{20}{60}{s} \\
                                     & & \\
    \qty{72}{\celsius}& \phantom{0}\qty{3}{min} \\
    \phantom{0}\qty{4}{\celsius} & \phantom{0}$\infty$ \\
    \midrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.